# Base64 images not showing in drupal website after integration with cloudfront

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-18.04, amazon-cloudfront, drupal7

I am receiving some issues on Drupal.

I have integrated Amazon cloudfront with Drupal.

The Cloudfront origin for my domain is drupal.example.com and Cnames are www.example.com and example.com. The problem is that some images are 
are forming the URL's like

"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7".

Please suggest.

Comment: Can you show an actual URL that has a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is occurred due to missing of base_url config in drupal settings.
Error resolved once base_url set in drupal setting file.